# closing bracket expected" when creating table in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-7

```
CREATE TABLE `actions` (
  `aid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'COMMENT
)
```

Here is the error Error

> Static analysis:
>
> 1 errors were found during analysis.
>
> ```
> A closing bracket was expected. (near ")" at position 76)
> ```
>
> SQL query:
>
> CREATE TABLE `actions` ( `aid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT
>   '0'COMMENT )
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near ')' at line 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you miss the comment string after `COMMENT`

```
 CREATE TABLE `actions` (
  `aid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'myComment'
)
```

For more Information about the `create table` Syntax see the [offical documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)

> column_definition:
>       data_type [NOT NULL | NULL] [DEFAULT default_value]
>         [AUTO_INCREMENT] [UNIQUE [KEY] | [PRIMARY] KEY]
>         [COMMENT 'string']
>         [COLUMN_FORMAT {FIXED|DYNAMIC|DEFAULT}]
>         [STORAGE {DISK|MEMORY|DEFAULT}]
>         [reference_definition]   | data_type [GENERATED ALWAYS] AS (expression)
>         [VIRTUAL | STORED] [UNIQUE [KEY]] [COMMENT comment]
>         [NOT NULL | NULL] [[PRIMARY] KEY]